this.router.events.filter is not a function
We have updated our project into Angular 17.
I got this ERROR TypeError: this.router.events.filter is not a function In console.
Here Is the app.components.ts file code
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { WINDOW } from '@ng-toolkit/universal';
import { Idle, DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES } from '@ng-idle/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { NgIdleKeepaliveModule } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoadingComponent } from './shared/components/loading/loading.component';
import { DataService } from './shared/service/data.service';
import { LoaderService } from './shared/service/loader.service';
import { SeoService } from './shared/service/seo.service';

declare const ga: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule, NgIdleKeepaliveModule, LoadingComponent, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [{ provide: WINDOW, useValue: {} }]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  title = 'motor-happy';
  serverName: String;
  idleState = 'Not started.';
  timedOut = false;
  lastPing?: Date = null;
  title1 = 'angular-idle-timeout';
  expiredDate: Date;
  constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) private window: any,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
    public router: Router,
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public titleService: Title,
    public meta: Meta,
    public cookieService: CookieService,
    public dataService: DataService,
    public loaderSVC: LoaderService,
    public seoService: SeoService,
    public idle: Idle,
  ) { 

    idle.setIdle(600);
    idle.setTimeout(600);
    idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);

    idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
      this.timedOut = true;
      localStorage.removeItem('authorisationToken');
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
    this.reset();
    this.serverName = environment.name;

    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      let utm_CampaignSource = params['utm_CampaignSource'];
      let getCookie = this.cookieService.get('utm_fetch');

      if (utm_CampaignSource && (!getCookie)) {
        const dateNow = new Date();
        dateNow.setMinutes(dateNow.getMinutes() + 30);
        this.cookieService.set('utm_fetch', "Yes", dateNow, '', '', true);
      }
    });

  }

  reset() {
    this.idle.watch();
    this.timedOut = false;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd && isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        if (this.serverName == "production") {
          ga('set', 'page', event.urlAfterRedirects);
          ga('send', 'pageview');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.seoService.createLinkForCanonicalURL();
    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      this.loaderSVC.startLoading();      
      if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
        return;
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.loaderSVC.stopLoading();        
      });
      if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
        sessionStorage.setItem('userAgent', userAgent);
        sessionStorage.setItem('ipAddress', '0.0.0.0');
      }
    });

    this.router.events
      .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
      .map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
      })
      .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
      .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this.updateDescription(event['description'], event['keywords'], event['title']);
      });
  }

  updateDescription(desc: string, keywords: string, title: string) {
    if (title) {
      this.titleService.setTitle(title);
    }
    if (desc) {
      this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: desc })
    }
    /*if(keywords){
      this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: keywords })
    }*/
  }
}

We have tried to update
this.router.events.filter
with
this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
But don't know how to map after that

As the Router.events property returns an observable, you should encapsulate all operators within the pipe. This is required to properly handle the stream of events emitted by the router. After chaining your operators with pipe, you can then subscribe to the observable to retrieve the desired values.
